# insmod: error inserting 'hello_world.ko': -1 Invalid module format

Tags: linux-kernel

My environment:

```
[root@localhost hello_world]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 15 04:27:16 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost hello_world]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
```

and kernel source tree version is:

```
[root@localhost lab]# ls /home/bruce/rpmbuild/BUILD/kernel-2.6.32-504.el6/
linux-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
[root@localhost lab]# rpm -qa kernel\* | sort
kernel-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
kernel-firmware-2.6.32-504.el6.noarch
kernel-headers-2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
```

that generated followed by wiki: [I Need the Kernel Source](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source)

A simple kernel "hello world":

```
#include <linux/module.h>       /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>       /* Needed for KERN_ALERT */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world.\n");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world.\n");
}
```

and Makefile:

```
KERNEL_SOURCE_VERSION ?= $(shell uname -r)
KERNEL_TREE ?= /lib/modules/$(KERNEL_SOURCE_VERSION)/build
obj-m += hello_world.o

all:
        make -C $(KERNEL_TREE) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C $(KERNEL_TREE) M=$(PWD) clean
```

it make successfully.

```
[root@localhost hello_world]# modinfo hello_world.ko
filename:       hello_world.ko
srcversion:     67A7C9765BA14A0A1C8B6CF
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.32 SMP mod_unload modversions
```

but when loads the hello_world.ko, it report errors:

```
[root@localhost hello_world]# insmod hello_world.ko
insmod: error inserting 'hello_world.ko': -1 Invalid module format
```

and log message shows:

```
[root@localhost hello_world]# tail -n 2 /var/log/messages 
Feb  2 22:09:47 localhost kernel: hello_world: no symbol version for module_layout
Feb  2 22:10:12 localhost kernel: hello_world: no symbol version for module_layout
```

It's my first kernel program, I think the version between kernel source and system kernel is matched. 
So what's the problem?

Comment: if compiles with the version matched kernel-devel, it loads successfully.

Comment: I solved it, "EXTRAVERSION" should configure in Makefile, details in [my blog](http://www.brucesky.com/articles/1229).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like init and exit are missing. It's explained in  [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-2)

```
module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```

Answer (score 0):

correct it and try

```
all:
        make -C $(shell KERNEL_TREE) M=$(shell PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C $(shell KERNEL_TREE) M=$(shell PWD) clean
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `$(MAKE)` instead of a single `make`, [See MAKE-Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKE-Variable.html), and maybe `CURDIR` instead of `shell PWD` as well, but I don't know the diff.